# The name 'Instantiate' does not exist in the current context

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I'm learning Unity C#, I was doing a tutorial from Unity, 2d roguelike, we are trying to instantiate the floor tiles, I did exactly the same as in the video (actually I even copied the code) but it shows me an error on the line

```
GameObject instance = Instantiate(toInstantiate, new Vector3(x, y, 0f), 
    Quaternion.identity) as GameObject;
```

specifically with `Instantiate(toInstantiate)`.

Can you help me?

```
using UnityEngine;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using Random = UnityEngine.Random;

public class BoardManager : MonoBehaviour 
{
    // Other class code omitted

    void BoardSetup()
    {
        boardHolder = new GameObject("Board").transform;

        for (int x = -1; x < columns + 1; x++)
        {
            for (int y = -1; y < rows + 1; y++)
            {
                GameObject toInstantiate = floorTiles[Random.Range(0, floorTiles.Length)];

                if (x == -1 || x == columns || y == -1 || y == rows)
                    toInstantiate = outerWallTiles[Random.Range(0, outerWallTiles.Length)];

                GameObject instance = Instantiate(toInstantiate, new Vector3(x, y, 0f), 
                    Quaternion.identity) as GameObject;

                instance.transform.SetParent(boardHolder);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Does your class inherit `MonoBehaviour` ?

Comment: yeah i think so, you mean this at the beginning right? 
public class BoardManager : MonoBehaviour {

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`Instantiate` is (usually) a reference to [`Object.Instantiate`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Object.Instantiate.html), so the class in which you're coding needs to derives from unity's [`Object`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Object.html) class; this is most commonly done by inheriting from [`MonoBehaviour`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/MonoBehaviour.html) which in turn inherits from `Object`. Keep in mind that any method you reference by name alone needs to exist within the same class or inheritance.

Comment: Hey! I changed it to  
GameObject instance =
                    GameObject.Instantiate (toInstantiate, new Vector3(x, y, 0f), Quaternion.identity) as GameObject;
that should do it right? or it should be like this?      UnityEngine.Object.Instantiate (toInstantiate, new Vector3(x, y, 0f), Quaternion.identity) as GameObject;

Comment: Actually that's a good catch - since the methods in question are static, you don't need an actual instance to call them.
I don't usually mess with setting position and rotation during the instantiate call, but api looks like it should be the latter

Answer (score 3):

See if you have the includes ("using directive") correct, and additionally, as @Haytam said, check if your class looks like this (note MonoBehaviour):

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;

public class YourTutorialClass : MonoBehaviour {
```

---

You can try an example from [the docs about Instantiate](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Object.Instantiate.html) to find your problem.

Comment: I'm sorry i'm pretty new at this, how can I check "using directive" and yeah the class is 
using UnityEngine;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using Random = UnityEngine.Random;

public class BoardManager : MonoBehaviour {

Comment: Not sure about `using Random = UnityEngine.Random` . by "includes" I mean the `using UnityEngine` lines. This is not '#include library.h' like in C++, it's called a "using directive" and instead of '#include' you use `using`. That's all.

Comment: are you 100% sure you spelled `Instantiate` correctly?

Answer (score 3):

You can also call it like `UnityEngine.Object.Instantiate` in the `Non-MonoBehaviour` C# class. You must include `using UnityEngine;` at the top of the class definition, though.

Comment: Classes instantiated by reading JSON via JsonUtility.FromJson cannot have MonoBehaviour for some reason. This solution works without the need for MonoBehaviour.